# How do I get the iPhone status bar to lay atop a UIImageView

Tags: iphone

One thing I like about the iPhone Photo Album is the way a photo extends up underneath both the navigation bar and the status bar which are both translucent.

In my app, I've got my navigation bar and status bar both translucent. How do I get the same visual effect as the Photo Album?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the manual.

This is the relevant property on UIViewControllers:

@property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL wantsFullScreenLayout